# Google Drive/Docs integration - multi-tenancy

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a multi-tenant application where user can store documents. I want to create integration with the Google Drive/Docs so user can open documents in Google Docs for editing and application can retrieve changed documents once the user is done. What is the best solution (authentication-wise) for this use case (multiple users/companies)? I created service account and am using the desktop credentials.

DriveService instantiation following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java):

```
    @Bean
    public Drive driveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
```

Can I instantiate `DriveService` for each user ie. with their credentials? Though that would imply I already have credentials, which I guess isn't safe? What are my options?

Edit 1:

Upload method:

```
public String uploadDocument() throws IOException {
        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/temp.docx");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(Files.probeContentType(filePath.toPath()), filePath);
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("name");
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");
        File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        return file.getId();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The credentials you get from GCP identify the client/application, not the end-user. And if you want to use both Docs API and Drive API, you have to build the two services, and use each of them for the corresponding methods you want to use.

Comment: @Iamblichus I understand that part. I have created the 2 services but I am creating the document on behalf on end user, am I not? I would have to create service for each user/company in order to create/manage documents for them? Or are you suggesting I create application account for which documents would be created and shared with specific user?

Comment: `I am creating the document on behalf on end user, am I not?` I guess so, you didn't provide any code related to that. The application will do things for the end user who is currently executing it. But you don't need to add any end-user "credentials". Also, why you are using a service account? In that case, if you want to create documents for several users (and not for the service account) you'll have to confer it domain-wide authority and use that to impersonate a regular account https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=el#delegatingauthority

Comment: @Iamblichus sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to create files on behalf of end user who can be from different companies. When user creates document in my app I want to upload it to their drive. If I understood correctly I would need OAuth Client ID, which I got, but I am wondering how should I authenticate users? Should I fetch their refresh token and save it in a database? I have added the method I am using for creating file.

Comment: Here you can see an [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) of the authentication process in Java. Yes, you should store the refresh token for future use.